# Animation anim_right.xml

Tags: android

What should i change to get anim_right.xml from the anim_left.xml. The opposite of the code below and someone can tell me good tutorial to learn animation in android please ?

ani_left.xml

```
<translate
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXDelta="50%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="0" />

<alpha
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `android:toXDelta` from `0` to `100`, that should work.